# Referencing multiple variables with the same prefix in R

Tags: r

Is it possible to reference multiple variables with the same prefix in R? Suppose you have a series of variables (A1, A2... Ax). I would like to define a series of variables (B1, B2... Bx) in terms of the A series of variables. The following example does not work, but I would like to define B1 and B2 as five times A1 and A2, respectively.

```
A1 <- 5
A2 <- 10

paste0("B",1:2) <-  5 * paste0("A",1:2)
```

In this case, the output should be: B1=25,B2=50. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This is an assignment problem. I do not understand why you would do this.. but anyway you can do `list2env(as.list(setNames(unlist(mget(ls(pattern='^A\\d$')))*5,paste0('B',1:2))),.GlobalEnv)`

Comment: now call `B1` or even`B2`

Comment: Can you include the expected output, it is not clear from the question.

Comment: You shouldn't create variables with the same prefix - you should be using a vector or a list. You are just making things hard on yourself otherwise. [See here for extended discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061).

Comment: I would do something similar to @Onyambu , `setNames(unlist(mget(paste0("A", 1:2))) * 5 , paste0("B", 1:2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way with `sapply`, `assign`, and `get`:

```
sapply(1:2, function(x) assign(paste0("B",x), 5*get(paste0("A", x)), pos=1))
```